# Find the position of a regex substring in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, substring

I need to extract a few fields of data from many lines of text. The data I am looking for is always in the same format ("from #.#####.##########") but it always contains different data. I know I can use regex to determine if that pattern is met... but I know the pattern is met. I want to know *where in the string* the pattern is met so that I can substring it out of there. Is that possible?

So a few of the lines of text might look like...
Oh, hello there. Blah blah blah. **from 1.12345.1234567890** doopeedoo whoop!
Lay tee dah good sir! **from 3.98766.123487650** and some other stuff!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As it goes, I'm not sure MySQL has a function for this, all the `REGEXP` commands appear to be boolean in return value.

Comment: Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Orbling noted, there doesn't seem to be a function for returning the string, only telling if it exists or not. I ended up using wild substring and index search functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/from \d+\.\d+\.\d+/
```

Your example on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/1HD0z9OVpb).

Comment: Thanks, but my issue isn't finding the string so much as doing something with that string.

Comment: What would you like to do with it?