# Mysql SQL query to get Last word in text

Tags: mysql, string, substring

I have a text similar to the below in my database

```
this is my car
how are you,doing
how is your)health
this is not(working
```

when I query database I should get the last words from this text. In this example

```
1st row should return "car"
2nd row should return "doing"
3rd row should return "health"
4th row should return "working"
```

any idea on how to get this?

Thanks for your help

Regards

Kiran

Comment: There is substring_index() function but in your case it doesn't work cause you have always different chars (spaces,commas, parentheses and so on). I think you need some regexp or you have to use a lot of nested replace to remove those chars before using that function.

Comment: I think you'd be better off just fetching each whole row and using RegEx (or whatever) to get the last word in your code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380692/find-the-position-of-a-regex-substring-in-mysql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example:

```
create table lastword (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
mytext varchar(250)
) engine = myisam;

insert into lastword (mytext) values 
('this is my car'),
('how are you,doing'),
('how is your)health'),
('this is not(working');

select *,
substring_index(replace(replace(replace(mytext,',',' '),')',' '),'(',' '),' ',-1) as last 
from lastword

+----+---------------------+---------+
| id | mytext              | last    |
+----+---------------------+---------+
|  1 | this is my car      | car     |
|  2 | how are you,doing   | doing   |
|  3 | how is your)health  | health  |
|  4 | this is not(working | working |
+----+---------------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see you would have to use a lot of nested replaces to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 3):

If the table is text, with columns ID and VALUE

```
select ID, RIGHT(VALUE, LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(VALUE))) FROM text;
```

The performance will probably suck if you end up with a couple of large text fields. Might want to rethink that approach.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice you had multiple delimiters: my query will only work if you normalize that. Either replace all delimiters with a fixed value or (what's probably the best option) add a column to store the last value and put it in there when you insert the row.

Comment: Thanks Femi for your quick response . I am able to get the results as expected with nick rulez query .. Once again thanks